# Does reading a text file in Java have a maximum line length?

Tags: java, xml, file, xpath

I'm reading in an XML configuration file that I don't control the format of, and the data I need is in the last element. Unfortunately, that element is a base64 encoded serialised Java class (yes, I know) that is 31200 characters in length.

Some experimenting seems to show that not only can the Java XML/XPath libraries not see the value in this element (they silently set the value to a blank string), if I just read the file into a string and print it out to console, everything (even a closing element on the *next* line) gets printed, but not this one element.

Finally, if I manually go into the file and break the line into rows, Java can see the line, although this obviously breaks XML parsing and deserialisation. It also isn't practical as I want to make a tool that will work across many such files.

Is there some line length limit in Java that stops this working? Can I get around it with a third party library?

**EDIT**: here's the XML-related code:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("path/to/xml/file.xml");
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = db.parse(fstream);
String s = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//el1").evaluate(d);
```

Comment: Well, the line limit is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` since that's the maximum possible value of `.length()`, but in this case it doesn't really help.

Comment: What library are you using? How are you reading the file (DOM, SAX, STaX)? For exmaple, JAXP has [a number of properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/index.html) that control the maximum size of some XML constructs that can be read which may be relevant to your situation.

Comment: I am using DOM, just the basic DocumentBuilder API. Added the code above.

Comment: Have you checked whether the `d` contains the required value, or at least elements named `<el1>`?

Answer (score -1):

For reading a large xml file, you can use SAX parser.
In addition to that reading the values inside the "characters" in the SAX parser should be read using "String Buffer" instead of String.
You can check out the SAX parser [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html).

Answer (score -1):

I wondered if it might be possible to do some pre-processing to the XML as you read it in.

I've been having a play to see if I could break down the long element into a list of sub-elements. Then this could be parsed and the sub-elements could be built back into a string. My testing threw up the fact that my initial guess of 4500 characters per sub element was still a bit high for my XML parsing to cope with, so I just arbitrarily picked 1000 and it seems to cope with that.

Anyway, this might help, it might not, but here's what I came up with:

```
private static final String ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_OPEN = "<element>";
private static final String ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_CLOSE = "</element>";
private static final String SUB_ELEMENT_OPEN = "<subelement>";
private static final String SUB_ELEMENT_CLOSE = "</subelement>";
private static final int SUB_ELEMENT_SIZE_LIMIT = 1000;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    try {

        /* The XML currently looks like this:
         * 
         * <root>
         * <element> ... Super long input with 30000+ characters ... </element>
         * </root>
         * 
         */
        final File file = new File("src\\main\\java\\longxml\\test.xml");
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while( line != null ) {
            if( line.contains(ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_OPEN) ) {
                buffer.append(ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_OPEN);
                String substring = line.substring(ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_OPEN.length(), (line.length() - ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_CLOSE.length()) );

                while( substring.length() > SUB_ELEMENT_SIZE_LIMIT ) {
                    buffer.append(SUB_ELEMENT_OPEN);
                    buffer.append( substring.substring(0, SUB_ELEMENT_SIZE_LIMIT) );
                    buffer.append(SUB_ELEMENT_CLOSE);

                    substring = substring.substring(SUB_ELEMENT_SIZE_LIMIT);
                }
                if( substring.length() > 0 ) {
                    buffer.append(SUB_ELEMENT_OPEN);
                    buffer.append(substring);
                    buffer.append(SUB_ELEMENT_CLOSE);
                }
                buffer.append(ELEMENT_TO_BREAK_UP_CLOSE);
            }
            else {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();


        /* The XML now looks something like this:
         * 
         * <root>
         * <element>
         * <subElement> ... First Part of Data ... </subElement>
         * <subElement> ... Second Part of Data ... </subElement>
         * ... Multiple Other SubElements of Data ..
         * <subElement> ... Final Part of Data ... </subElement>
         * </element>
         * </root>
         */

        //This parses the xml with the new subElements in
        final InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(buffer.toString()));
        final Node document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src).getFirstChild();

        //This gives us the first child (element) then that's children (subelements)
        final NodeList childNodes = document.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();

        //Then concatenate them back into a big string.
        final StringBuilder finalElementValue = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++ ) {
            final Node node = childNodes.item(i);
            finalElementValue.append( node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() );
        }

        //At this point do whatever you need to do. Decode, Deserialize, etc...
        System.out.println(finalElementValue.toString());
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There are a few issues with this in terms of it's general application:

- It does rely on the element you want to break up being uniquely identifiable. (But I'm guessing the logic to find the element can be improved quite a bit)
- It relies on knowing the format of the XML and hoping that doesn't change. (Only in the latter parsing section, you could potentially parse it better with xPath once it has been broken into subelements)

Having said all of that, you do end up with a parsable XML string, which you can build your encoded string from, so this might help you on your way to a solution.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin That is a very fair comment, and usually I wouldn't, but I'm proposing preforming some pre-processing of the XML file, before parsing it, in order to make the file parsable by usual methods. I wonder how it would be possible to do this pre-processing without reading the file by hand?